# Opencart 3.0 to Get Products of Category Id in Loop

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3

On my opencart 3.0 store I would like to display the products of a certain category on another category page as well as the products already showing. I want to show the accessories for a product series on the same page of the series.

I was wondering if it were possible to display this product loop,

`{% for product in products %} //loop in a .twig file`

but make it only pull products where the category Id is something I determine. Anyway I could do this, as well as use it pull data from different categories in a different loops?

Let me know I need to rephase my question or add more. Thanks!!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just assign the product to multiple categories in the backend?

Comment: To appear on the same page?--yes, the problem is that one category is the main product the client is wanting consumers to buy, the other category is the attachments for the first category. He doesn't want them blended but wants it to say  "Accessories" below the other products on that category page.

Comment: Have you considered using Options rather? What you want to do is perfectly achievable in code but it's much simpler in the long run to use the default functionality. Why not use the same approach discussed in your previous question where we had "products2"?

Comment: I actually did use that same approach! So again thanks! I guess my question was a duplicate! That other method works great!